# Scala - graceful map lookup failure

Tags: scala, dictionary, return, arguments, default-value

Let's say I want a Map, that if I fail to look up a certain value in, should trigger an abort of the whole procedure.

E.g. (simplified):

```
def myMethod = {
    val res = foo(Map[String,String](("hello" -> "Hello")),false)
    if(!res) println("World!")
}

def foo(myMap:Map[String,String],myDefault:Boolean):Boolean = {
    val actualDefault = baz(myDefault)
    val m = myMap.withDefault{
        case _ => return actualDefault
    }
    bar((s:String) => m(s))
    return true
}

def bar(lookup:String => String):Unit = {
    print(lookup("hello") + " ")
    println(lookup("world"))
}

def baz(myDefault:Boolean):Boolean = false
```

The behaviour of this is perfect in my case, where `bar` is called many times from `foo` and a single error in any one invocation should result in `foo`'s returning an error-independent default value.

**But**, I'm having serious doubts that this is a suggested practice.

Is there an alternative (better) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much more idiomatic to perform your map lookups in the `Option` monad. This allows you to stop subsequent lookups once one fails, and also to provide a default value. For example, if we have this map:

```
val myMap = Map("foo" -> "bar", "hello" -> "world", "a" -> "b")
```

We can write this:

```
val result: String = (
  for {
    f <- myMap.get("foo")
    h <- myMap.get("hello")
    a <- myMap.get("a")
  } yield s"$f $h $a"
).getOrElse("my default")
```

And we'll get `"bar world b"`. If we tried to look up a key that didn't exist in the map, we'd get the default:

```
scala> val result: String = (
     |   for {
     |     f <- myMap.get("foo")
     |     x <- myMap.get("x")
     |     h <- myMap.get("hello")
     |     a <- myMap.get("a")
     |   } yield s"$f $x $h $a"
     | ).getOrElse("my default")
result: String = my default
```

I'm not sure I understand your exact use case, but you should be able to rewrite it in terms of a `for`-comprehension (or a desugared version using `map` and `flatMap` with `myMap.get`).

Comment: Use case would be reconstructing an immutable tree where a failed lookup anywhere down the tree makes the reconstruction impossible. As the tree's immutable, we can just throw away everything we've been doing since passing the map to the subtree and return the original node.